# in bash,now i have two strings,one is 'a b c' while another is '1 2 3' any good way to combine them to 'a=1 b=2 c=3' I

Tags: shell

in bash,now i have two strings,one is 'a b c' while another is '1 2 3'
any good way to combine them to 'a=1 b=2 c=3'
I tried string to array and combined them.but if i don't know the IFS?

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a array1 <<< "$upvote_count"
IFS=' ' read -r -a array0 <<< "$qids"
tLen=${#array[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ));
do
  echo "${array0[$i]}"" ""${array1[$i]}">>a.txt
done
```

Comment: Your example looks like it should work fine without setting `IFS`. It seems like you're asking how to do something that you can already do but then your last sentence is asking about something completely different. Please can you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: You appear to have a typo when setting `tLen`. `array` is not defined, just `array0` and `array1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create arrays from each string[1] and then use `eval` to create the variables with names from *string 1* and values from *string 2* by looping over each array element and evaluating `array1[i]=array2[i]` (pseudocode). A short script would look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

v1="a b c"              ## original string variables
v2="1 2 3"

ar1=( $(echo $v1) )     ## create arrays 1 & 2 from strings
ar2=( $(echo $v2) )

for ((i=0; i<${#ar1[@]}; i++)); do
    eval "${ar1[i]}=${ar2[i]}"          ## eval to create variables
done                                    ## (be careful with eval)

printf "a=%s\nb=%s\nc=%s\n" $a $b $c    ## confirm
```

**Output**

```
$ bash evalabc.sh
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

You would want to add validations that the you have the same number of elements in each array, that the elements of the first don't begin with numbers, etc.. **and** that they do not contain anything that would be harmful when you run `eval`!

As noted in the comment of the script, take *great care* in using `eval` (or avoid it altogether) because it will do exactly what you tell it to do. You would **not** want to have, e.g. `a=sudo rm`, `b="-rf"`, `c=/*` and then `eval "$a $b $c"` -- very bad things can happen.

**Footnotes:**

[1] (adjust `IFS` as needed - not needed for space separation)

Answer (score 0):

Give this tested version a try:

```
unset letters; unset figures; IFS=' ' read -r -a letters <<< "a b c" ; \
IFS=' ' read -r -a figures <<< '1 2 3' ; \
for i in "${!letters[@]}" ; do \
    printf "%s=%s\n" ${letters[i]} ${figures[i]}; \
done
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Answer (score -1):

A general method that works in any Bourne shell, (not just *bash*):  Use a *for* loop for one list (a b c), match it up with piped input for the second list (1 2 3), produce a string of shell code, and *eval* that.

```
eval $(seq 3 | for f in a b c ; do read x ; echo $f=$x ; done) ;
echo $a $b $c
```

which prints:

```
1 2 3
```

*eval* is needed because variables assigned in a loop are forgotten once the loop is over.

Caution:  never let *eval* execute unknown code.  If either list contained unwanted shell code delimiters or commands, further parsing would be necessary, i.e. a prophylactic pipe after '*; done*'.

Applied to the specific example in the starting question, with two strings, containing space separated lists, we get:

```
qids="a b c"  # our variable names
unset $qids   # clear them if need be
upvote_count="1 2 3"   # the values to be assigned
# generate code to assign the names list to the values list,
# via a 'for' loop, the index $var_name is for the $qids,
# and assign $var_name to each $upvote_count value which we pipe in.
# Since an assignment can't leave the loop, we 'echo'
# the code for assignment, and 'eval' that code after the loop
# is done.
eval $(
       echo "${upvote_count}" |
       tr ' ' '\n' |
       for var_name in $qids ; do
           read value
           echo "$var_name=$value"
       done
      )
# The loop is done, so test if the code worked:
for var_name in $qids
do
    echo -n $var_name=
    eval echo \$$var_name
done
```

...which outputs:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```